# Netbeans Combo Box Looping with a range number? 1900-1901 to 2000-2001

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans, jcombobox

as the title says.

My codes in looping a year in a combo box in netbeans

```
 for (int i = 1900; i <= 2015 ; i ++){
        SchoolYear.addItem(i);
    }
```

SchoolYear is my combo box .

Now, i want to loop the display in my combo box 1900-1901 to 2014-2015? Should i do it on manual?no other way?
Please give me some ideas .

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes. it's working fine. The combo box shows 1900 to 2015, what im trying to get is to display  in the combobox (range) 1900-1901 to 2014-2015. Yassin answer is correct.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 for (int i = 1900; i < 2015 ; i ++){
        SchoolYear.addItem(i + "-" + (i+1)); // Output : 1900-1901
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ! i don't need answer. A hint is enough. Thanks again!

Comment: @SevyNnez no problem. Do not forget to accept and upvote